# Ruby: Get currently logged in user on windows

Tags: windows, ruby, single-sign-on

In C# I can get the current user of a web app using the HttpContext, however, I can't figure out how to do this in Ruby. Is there any way of doing this?

**FOR THOSE OF YOU SAYING IT IS IMPOSSIBLE, HERES PROOF:**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/How_to_NT_User_Name.aspx

Comment: what is your criteria for defining what a 'current user' is?

Comment: Try this: `%x(echo %USERNAME%)`

Comment: My criteria is whatever the username is for the user that is currently logged into the windows machine that is accessing the web page.

Comment: i dont think you will be able to get at the username for the machine, that is outside the scope of the browser security sandbox.

Comment: Impossible by "normal means". It would require a plugin to be installed on each client (be it Java, Flash, or a custom one). Why do you want to know the username used to login on the client system? Makes no sense to me. Are you sure C# gets that information from a remote client?

Comment: I was under the impression HttpContext pulled it from the HTTP headers as any other normal authentication middleware.  Perhaps the current user uses the same name as his Windows login?  Otherwise, I agree with jweyrich, I don't see how this could be passed through.

Comment: What webserver are you using?  The link you provide implies that this information can be pulled from the AUTH_USER server environment variable.  For some reason, I suspect it might be an IIS type thing.  REMOTE_USER should be a bit more cross-platform (but I'm not confident).

Comment: @WedTM: The presented article/code uses an authentication mechanism (NTLM, etc), which you didn't mention in your original question. In fact, we had no clue about that, but now it makes sense. So, the authentication mechanism is already configured and working?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, to get the current username, there's this:

```
puts ENV['USERNAME']
```

Or go to the Win32API.

```
require 'dl/win32'

def get_user_name
  api = Win32API.new(
    'advapi32.dll',
    'GetUserName',
    'PP',
    'i'
  )

  buf = "\0" * 512
  len = [512].pack('L')
  api.call(buf,len)

  buf[0..(len.unpack('L')[0])]
end

puts get_user_name
```

Edit:  And I'm an idiot.  This isn't what you asked for at all.  Oh well, it took me time to dig this out of my code, so it might as well stay here for anyone else wondering :P

Edit again:  OK, it turns out I'm not an idiot after all.  This *is* what you want.  When I went back and re-read your question, the HttpContext threw me off, and I thought it was the current username from HTTP auth or something.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried it.

Comment: Rails will get server's username, ain't it? How could we get client's username instead?

Answer (score 1):

To get the username of the current user on client machine you can use this

ENV['USERNAME']

Comment: Rails will get server's username instead of client's.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails try: `request.env['HTTP_REMOTE_USER']`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is how you can retrieve the username that the user used to login to the web application.  That will differ depending on what authentication mechanism you're using.  Some Apache authentication modules, for example, will pass REMOTE_USER (e.g. the Kerberos module), the CAS Single-Sign-On module passes CAS-USER, etc.  Standard digest authentication and such uses the Authentication header.  You should be able to access these using request.env[HEADER] as someone else pointed out above.  Check out the documentation on how your authentication layer is passing on the user in the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Is your c# code running as a .NET plugin/client-side code or is it ENTIRELY server side? Your ruby code would be entirely server side. According to the MS docs, only stuff running in the CLR sandbox can really get to that information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163700.aspx (under Defining the sandbox).

One thing interesting to note is that sites registered under LocalIntranet have access to that information. I'm not sure off hand how this maps to security zones in IE though.

The thing to understand is that LOGON_USER is NOT visible to the browser sandbox anymore than the browser can see the contents of a filesystem path on your system. The fact that your c# code sees it almost certainly indicitive of some clientside component passing it upstream.

You have the option of implementing mod_ntlm under apache and pushing the headers downstream. I don't have the points to post a second link but google 'rails ntlm sso' and see the rayapps.com link.

but if your app isn't Rails based, you'll have to port that to your server code. You can also checkout rack-ntlm if your app is rack compliant.

Comment: Nope, there is no client side code. I am sure of that.

Here's a codeproject sample of what's going on. 

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/How_to_NT_User_Name.aspx

Answer (score 0):

***[RUBY ON RAILS ONLY]***

This is what worked for me but there are some limitations:

- [won't work in Chrome: `undefined method 'encode' for nil:NilClass`](https://github.com/rekado/ntlm-sso/issues/2)
- [won't validate user credentials](https://github.com/rekado/ntlm-sso/issues/3)

If you don't care about these issues, go ahead:

1. In your rails application, add Rekado's gem to your Gemfile: `gem 'ntlm-sso', '=0.0.1'`
2. Create an initialiser `config/initializers/ntlm-sso.rb` with:

   ```
   require 'rack'
   require 'rack/auth/ntlm-sso'

   class NTLMAuthentication
     def initialize(app)
       @app = app
     end

     def call(env)
       auth = Rack::Auth::NTLMSSO.new(@app)
       return auth.call(env)
     end
   end
   ```
3. On your `application.rb` file, add the line: `config.middleware.use "NTLMAuthentication"`
4. Call `request.env["REMOTE_USER"]` on your view or controller to get current username.

*PS: Let me know if you find anyway to make it work on Chrome or to validate user credentials.*