# Rails get username of currently logged windows user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to get the username of the currently logged windows user. Could it be done easily?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a way to read a clients windows login name using ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506932/is-there-a-way-to-read-a-clients-windows-login-name-using-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3):

The username of the account running the script can be accessed via something like:

`puts ENV['USERNAME']`

Beware that if you're running it as a system service the username will probably come back as "SYSTEM"

If that isn't enough to suite your needs there is an alternative method outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3544741/648695

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Ruby `etc` module

```
require 'etc'
Etc.getlogin
```

The doc is avaiable here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html#method-c-getlogin

Returns the short user name of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, unless you're using active directory that would require a microsoft framework website, I don't think you'll find a way in rails.

There are a few discussion points here that may help: [Can you get a Windows (AD) username in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php)

Comment: I am using active directory so there is a way do that? `

Comment: Read Dylans answer on the link I posted and give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Same question here: [is there a way to read a clients windows login name using ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506932/is-there-a-way-to-read-a-clients-windows-login-name-using-ruby-on-rails/30855815#30855815)

Anyways, just copying my own answer below...

---

This is what worked for me but there are some limitations:

- [won't work in Chrome: `undefined method 'encode' for nil:NilClass`](https://github.com/rekado/ntlm-sso/issues/2)
- [won't validate user credentials](https://github.com/rekado/ntlm-sso/issues/3)

If you don't care about these issues, go ahead:

1. In your rails application, add Rekado's gem to your Gemfile: `gem 'ntlm-sso', '=0.0.1'`
2. Create an initialiser `config/initializers/ntlm-sso.rb` with:

   ```
   require 'rack'
   require 'rack/auth/ntlm-sso'

   class NTLMAuthentication
     def initialize(app)
       @app = app
     end

     def call(env)
       auth = Rack::Auth::NTLMSSO.new(@app)
       return auth.call(env)
     end
   end
   ```
3. On your `application.rb` file, add the line: `config.middleware.use "NTLMAuthentication"`
4. Call `request.env["REMOTE_USER"]` on your view or controller to get current username.

*PS: Let me know if you find anyway to make it work on Chrome or to validate user credentials.*